# Flask module not found in WGSI

Tags: python

I am building a Flask app. The directory structure is as follows:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   app.py
│
├───static
├───templates
├───vision
│   │   vi_img.py
│   │   yolov5l.pt
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───data
│   ├───models
│   │   │   common.py
│   │   │   experimental.py
│   │   │   export.py
│   │   │   yolo.py
│   │   │   yolov5l.yaml
│   │   │   yolov5m.yaml
│   │   │   yolov5s.yaml
│   │   │   yolov5x.yaml
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   ├───hub
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │
│   ├───utils
│   ├───weights
```

Inside the vi_img.py file in the vision directory, 'import vision.models.experimental'

The flask app loads but later says that the 'models' module could not be found!

[image: Module not found]

I do not have the faintest idea of what is happening here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
import vision.models.experimental
```

use

```
import .models.experimental
```

since `vi_img.py` module and `models` package are on same level under `vision` package

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with wrong referencing while importing the module. I decided to take the 'vision' module and convert it into a web API in itself